# Why the asp datagrid header is rendered as TR instead of TH? How to Render the Header of grid as TH

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to render the header text as TH instead of TR

```
    <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                CssClass="rgform" PageSize="3" Width="100%">
           <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="rgAltRow" />
           <ItemStyle CssClass="rgRow" />
           <HeaderStyle CssClass="rgHeader" />
             <Columns>
              <asp:BoundColumn DataField="project_id" HeaderText="Project Id">
              </asp:BoundColumn>
             </Columns>
    </asp:datagrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this attribute: `" UseAccessibleHeader="True"` to your DataGrid.

This will replace TD with TH in your column header TR